# How to stream tweets using twitter API V2?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to stream tweets using twitter API V.2. But the online tutorial that I am following uses API v1. I looked at the documentation, I understand that I should use `(tweepy.StreamingClient)` now instead? But I cannot find any examples on how to stream tweets. How can I convert the code below so that it works for API v2?

```
import tweepy

# API KEYS
bearer_token = ""
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

# authorisation
client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key= consumer_key, consumer_secret= consumer_secret,access_token= access_token,access_token_secret= access_token_secret)

# not working 
class Listener(tweepy.Stream):
  
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True


twitter_stream = Listener(
    consumer_key, consumer_secret,
    access_token, access_token_secret
)

twitter_stream.filter(track=['#Bitcoin'])
```

Edit: my attempt to solve

```
class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    # This function gets called when the stream is working
    def on_connect(self):
        print("Connected")

    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
       print(tweet.data) 
       return


stream = MyStream(bearer_token=bearer_token)
stream.filter(track=['#Bitcoin'])
```

Comment: Have you looked at twitter's documentation? 
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/api-reference/get-tweets-search-stream

Answer (score 1):

In the new `StreamingClient` some of the old options for `stream.filter()` have been removed. (track, follow, etc)

Instead you have to use the new `StreamingClient.add_rules()` and use `tweepy.StreamRule("text rule here")`

---

How to use rules is documented here. For instance `"hello"` would search for tweets matching hello, `"hello OR #greeting"` would match a tweet with hello or the #greeting
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/build-a-rule

I'd recommend taking a look at the Operators table in that article

---

```py
class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    # This function gets called when the stream is working
    def on_connect(self):
        print("Connected")

    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
       print(tweet.data) 
       return


stream = MyStream(bearer_token=bearer_token)
stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("#Bitcoin")) #adding the rules
stream.filter() #runs the stream
```